# Why adding two points by adding coordinates is wrong?

Tags: math, graphics, addition, points

I study IT and i have to show that adding two points by adding coordinates is bad idea. I don't know why? (except numerical problems). Has it something to do with  parallelogram?
Sorry for my English. Greets.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding two points" ?

Comment: Can you explain further: what points ? cartesian (x,y) space or (geographical) spherical latitdue, longitude  coordinates?

Comment: Adding two points? Do you mean vectors?

Comment: I am not sure because it is not written in task but probably (x,y) + (a,b) = (x+a,y+b)

Comment: Explain the example of why the operation of adding points by coordinates
It is not a good idea. // excercise would be sth like that in english

Comment: One does not add points. One adds vectors or translates a point by adding a vector to it (in the linear case, where the translation group of the affine or point space is a vector space).

Comment: Do you think it is enough to tell the tutor that? I was thinking about it. I suppose he needs more :( but i have no idea what @LutzL And the question is what is other idea of adding points ;) or just is no sens in any adding

Comment: The distinction between points and translations is (slightly) pedantic. However, it could be an answer if that distinction already played a role. And, as already pointed out, when curved coordinates are in play, addition of points makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends strongly on the context.  But it does often makes sense to discriminate between points and vectors.  And, if you are making that kind of distinction, then vectors can be added to each other, but points should not be.

Conceptually speaking, the point indicates a *location*, while a vector indicates a *distance* in a particular *direction*.

Mathematically speaking, the idea is that, unlike a vector space, a geometric space doesn't have an origin -- so you provide only the operations that reflect those principles.

The distinction is somewhat pedantic, in that the underlying representation of your geometric points will almost certainly be the same as the vector.  However, it may make sense for your API to reflect the mathematical principles, because it makes certain kinds of programming errors more difficult.

Practically speaking, a vector is the *difference* between two points.  So, you can subtract two points to get a vector, and you can add a vector to a point to get another point.  Vectors can be scaled, added, subtracted, dot-producted, etc. with other vectors as normal, though.  The net effect of the API restriction is to require you to subtract points first to get a vector, before doing vector math -- then, applied relative to an existing point if you need to output a point result.

Both points and vectors can be represented uniformly by using homogeneous coordinates:  vectors will have the extra coordinate `w=0`, while points will have `w!=0`.  In this context, finding a geometric vector between two points is complex because you need to normalize them to `w=1` first, and it is especially important to avoid carelessly adding two points, because the result will generally not behave in a way that makes much geometric sense...

Comment: BIG THANKS I hope that is all what i should explain during presentation of answer to the question ;)

Comment: Just did a minor update to the explanation...

Comment: If you have the time, I would recommend some reading on basic computer graphics, as well.

Comment: any recommendations?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382614/how-to-add-two-points-on-an-elliptic-curve is that sth about that?

Comment: that math.stackexchange question is very specialized from your POV, I would not worry about it.  For an intro CG text, I like Alan Watt's _3D Computer Graphics_, but your best bet may be to browse that section of your school library, so you can see which books make the most sense to you.